# How to use Java Regex to sanitize html that accept only <b> and <i> tag?

Tags: java, regex

Ok, let say I got `textarea` and user can input any sort of text into it.

Then I want to put this text into a `div` element. For example,

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=text;
```

The issue is that user can put html code into it and it can distort the `div`. However, the text can contain `<b>` or `<i>`.

So I want to replace all `<` with `&lt;` & all `>` with `&gt;` &  except `<b>` or `<i>`.

Note that: space before and after `i` are allowed so we will keep `<i >` , `< i>`, `<   i >`, etc. Also, `<b>` / `</b>` & `<i>` / `</i>` must go in pair. That means if there is a `<b>` but there is no `</b>` then it should escape `<b>` & it should do the same with `<i>`.

**so, How to use Java Regex to sanitize html that accept only `<b>` and `<i>` tag?**

Comment: If you want to enforce pairing, and since pairs can be nested, you cannot use regex, because Java's regex doesn't support nesting.

Comment: Obligatory reading : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: OK, SO deleted my edit of my comment.  Please use an HTML parser instead of a REGEX for this.

Comment: Is a space before the tag name legal html ?

Comment: @sln Not sure, but it's not allowed in XML, however web browser HTML parsers are notoriously lenient, so they may allow it regardless of specifications.

Comment: How about using \*italic\*, \*\*blold\*\* instead of <i>italic</i>, <b>bold</b>.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enforce pairing with regex, but if you simply want to eliminate all html artifacts, except `<b>` and `<i>` and their matching end tags, you need two `replaceAll()` calls.

```
input.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<(?!/?\\s*[bi]\\s*>)", "&lt;");
```

Comment: In case "there is a <b> but there is no </b>".

Comment: @saka1029 You could just generate `<div> user text here </b></i></div>`. That way, any unended **bold** or *italic* tags started by user text will be ended. Or you could use something other than regex. Or you could do some regex `find()` after the `replaceAll()` calls to check if there are unended **bold** or *italic* tags, then end only when needed.